# How to redirect using .htaccess instead of searching for subdirectory and remove .php extension also

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have folder structure like

index.php

blog.php

contact.php

these are in root directory
I need to open
http://myproject.com

http://myproject.com/contact

http://myproject.com/blog

http://myproject.com/blog/abc-blog-post     // abc-blog-post is slug of the post for single page here we have to redirect to blog.php

till now I  have removed .php from URL using .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ /$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /blog [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [NC,END]
```

The rule I added to your htaccess maps any URI string that looks something like `blog/foobar` to `/blog.php` . If you want to access the GET variable on your blog.php file , just add `q=$1` to the destination file in rule.

Comment: where to add q=$1, but I need Url = $1 where to put that

Comment: @RajKumarSharma `RewriteRule ^blog/(.+)$ /blog.php?url=$1 [L]`